# SwiftUI and AVPlayer

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to get an AVPlayer layer in my SwiftUI interface.
Google doesn't have many answers on the subject, in fact, there was a tutorial that looked promising see: https://medium.com/@chris.mash/avplayer-swiftui-b87af6d0553. But it was full of bugs. So, I tried going about this my own way.

The plan: create a UIView subclass and add an AVPlayerLayer to it, then, wrap the UIView for SwiftUI.

The results: nothing.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
struct PlayerView : UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return PlayerViewSwift()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

And then the PlayerViewSwift class:

```
class PlayerViewSwift : UIView {
   private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .infinite)


    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)


    }



    // This attribute hides `init(coder:)` from subclasses
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
         super.layoutSubviews()
      //  playerLayer.player =

        print("hmmm")

               let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u80")!)
               player.play()

               playerLayer.player = player
               layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)


     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing "0" from the URL path extension, so that it is "m3u8" instead of "m3u80".

Also, set `playerLayer`'s frame equal to `PlayerViewSwift`'s bounds in the end of `layoutSubviews()`:

```
self.playerLayer.frame = self.bounds
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5.1, iOS 13.

I read Chris Mash tutorials too [there for 4 of them] and put this together. I certainly don't recall them being full of bugs, maybe a few typos.

It plays either an embedded video or a streaming one in SwiftUI navigation controller managed page.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import Combine

let timePublisher = PassthroughSubject<TimeInterval, Never>()
let videoFinished = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
let nextFrame = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

 struct PlayerTimeView: View {
 @State private var currentTime: TimeInterval = 0

var body: some View {
Text("\(currentTime)")
.onReceive(timePublisher) { time in
  self.currentTime = time
}.statusBar(hidden: true)
.navigationBarHidden(true)
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}
}

class PlayerUIView: UIView {
private var timeObservation: Any?
private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: .zero)
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppDemo", withExtension: "mov")
//    let url = URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")!
//    let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XK8METRgK_U")!
let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
player.play()

  timeObservation = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 0.5, preferredTimescale: 600), queue: nil) { [weak self] time in
  guard let self = self else { return }
  // Publish the new player time
  print("time.seconds ", time.seconds)
  timePublisher.send(time.seconds)

  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.finishVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
}

playerLayer.player = player
layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
}
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -115, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
 }

 @objc func finishVideo() {
    print("Video Finished")
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)
     videoFinished.send()
     nextFrame.send()
  }

}

struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
 func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
 }
 func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
     PlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
 }
}

struct PlayerPage: View {
 @EnvironmentObject var env: MyAppEnvironmentData
 @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation

 var body: some View {
   VStack {
     PlayerView().onReceive(videoFinished) { (_) in
       self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
     }
   HStack {
     Spacer()
     PlayerTimeView()
     Spacer()
   }
  }
}
}
```